# jquery calendar stops working on desktop but works on mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, calendar

having a strange problem with jquery calendar, my code is in a block (widget) in flatsome theme wordpress, it is the same block i am using for both desktop and mobile version of the header builder.It opens the calendar in mobile and not desktop, if i swap things around, it will open in desktop and not mobile.

is my code correct for the calendar or is there a glaring problem here
theme child function below

```
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
}

function custom_style_sheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-styling', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().
        '/datepicker.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_style_sheet');
```

calendar form code

```
<form class="bookingquery" action="externalurl" autocomplete="off" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" target="_blank">
<input id="In" class="checkin" style="width: 100%; height :50px; 
cursor: pointer;" name="In" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" placeholder="Check In" />
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#In').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            minDate: 0,
            yearRange: '00:+02',
            orientation: "top",
            autoclose: true,
            yearSuffix: ''
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="Out" class="checkout" style="width: 100%; height :50px; 
cursor: pointer;" name="Out" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" placeholder="Check Out" />
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#Out').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            minDate: +1,
            yearRange: '00:+02',
            orientation: "top",
            autoclose: true,
            yearSuffix: ''
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="Guests" name="Guests" type="hidden" value="2" />
<button class="form-submit-booking" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that flatsome theme has conflict in header as it calls the code twice
works fine in a page